# JetBrains can not connect with a Hosted MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, firewall, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I have a MySQL-Database from a hostingservice (strato.de). I try to connect the JetBrains DataGrip with this MySQL Database. I tried to connect but I get everytime a timeout. So I tried it with SSH but there I got this error:

> [08001] Could not create connection to database server. Attempted
>   reconnect 3 times. Giving up. java.io.EOFException: Can not read
>   response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before
>   connection was unexpectedly lost.

I do not understand the problem... is the Firewall blocking the connection?
How can I connect JetBrains with my Hosted MySQL-Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your hosting provider exposed MySQL database port for external connections. 
Have you tried to connect via MySQL Workbench?

Just in case read [JetBrains help topic](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/connecting-to-a-database.html#connect-to-mysql-database)